# Can you have multiple HTML images from one php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently learned that you can use a php file as a source for an img in HTML.

Example: `<img src="image.php">`

I'm trying to use this method to get multiple images from another folder on the server, and showing them to the user. However, I can't get this to work.

The JS code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < imgAmount; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += '<img src="image.php">';
}
```

`image.php` code:

```
session_start();
$path = '../images/*';
$images = glob($path);
if ($_SESSION["imgCurrent"] < $_SESSION["imgAmount"]) {
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  readfile($images[$_SESSION["imgCurrent"]]);
  $_SESSION["imgCurrent"] = $_SESSION["imgCurrent"]+1;
}
```

`imgAmount` from the JS code, and `$_SESSION["imgCurrent"]` `$_SESSION["imgAmount"]`from the `image.php` code are declared in another file, and they are working properly. For some reason **all** the images end up being the same picture. It's **always** the image that's in the position of the `$images` array equal to the value of `$_SESSION["imgCurrent"]` when it's first declared, so 0 by default. When changing the starting value to another number, the image changes too. At first glance it looks like the variable isn't changing, however returning the value of `$_SESSION["imgCurrent"]` back to the JS code and using `console.log` shows that the variable is increasing properly.

I also tested with `window.open("URL/image.php");` instead of the `img` tag, and that worked properly aswell. All the pictures showed up correctly in seperate tabs.

This is probably a very bad way to do what I'm trying to do, so if anyone has a simpler method, I'm all ears. However, **I have to use php**, as the folder containing the images is not reachable by HTML.

Comment: How are you "_returning the value of `$_SESSION["imgCurrent"]` back to the JS code_"? Also, for your increment, you could just do `$_SESSION['imgCurrent'] += 1;`

Comment: I'm returing the value with AJAX (replacing where I make the img tag)

Comment: Could be a caching issue. Are you sure your browser is fetching a number of images and not only one and caching it?

Comment: You have to set $_SESSION["imgCurrent"] and $_SESSION["imgAmount"] values initially

Comment: It's also not very clear why you are using session values for this

Comment: @ArayniMax they are set in a different file. imgAmount is set to the amount of images it can find, and imgCurrent is set to 0

Comment: kk, as @GrumpyCrouton said. You should not use session vars for this
You should take a look at url parameters

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I know I should increment like that, but I'm still a little bit unsure how session variables work so I wanted to be safe. And I'm using session because thats the only way I see how I can "pass" values between the JS code and the image.php

Comment: Maybe a race condition. Your browser will make multiple calls in parallel. It is possible that you are loading multiple images BEFORE updating the counter.
Update the counter first to avoid this problem.
But @ArayniMax is right, use parameters.

Comment: @NitroFray Session variables work like any other variables, they are just normally used for things relating to a specific user and not something like total amount of images stored in a directory. They have more overhead, so shouldn't be used for something like this.

Comment: Is it possible to use url parameters like this: `<img src="image.php?value=0">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the session variables and using url parameters instead, made the code work correctly. All images are showing up.

Example: `<img src="image.php?value=0">`